# Unable to deactivate context org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.LazyHttpConversationContextImpl when destroying request HttpServletRequestImpl

Tags: jsf, wildfly, jboss-weld, jakarta-ee-security-api

I am replacing j_security_check with my own custom login method and the user is logged in successfully, however when it is time to redirect to home page, I keep getting this error:

```
 Unable to deactivate context org.jboss.weld.module.web.context.http.LazyHttpConversationContextImpl@eea78ad when destroying request HttpServletRequestImpl
```

I used [this](https://github.com/rieckpil/blog-tutorials/blob/master/jsf-simple-login-with-java-ee-security-api/src/main/java/de/rieckpil/blog/LoginBacking.java) as a guide to create my login setup, except I customized the continueAuthentication() func and it returns SUCCESS but it is unable to redirect. I did some googling but I still did not find a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in WildFly. It's already reported as [WFLY-15972](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/WFLY-15972) and currently still open.

There's little you can do until they fix it. It has no harm on endusers.

Answer (score -1):

The component you use to login, propably a commandbutton, should use a return String from your submit() function for its outcome or action attribute.

If the login succeded you simply return the page you want to redirect to.

You can also implement your own webfilter in combination with a session scoped bean to keep the logged in user and redirect to your login page per default if no logged in user is present.

Here is a little example: https://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/webfilter-annotation-examples